# python append list only gets last value

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

Again with a problem, this time it's about lists.
I already know that I can put lists into lists but if I do that, all mini lists are just the last list I put in. Here is my program:

```
g = int(input ('How many lists?'))
while g > 0 :
    Zwi.clear()
    print('')
    print('')
    print('')      
    co = float(input ('object 1'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 2'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 3'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 4'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    Coords.append(Zwi)
    g = g - 1
print(Coords)
```

For example, if I put in 4 Lists and then

1,2,3,4

2,4,3,1

7,4,2,5

9,8,7,6

it only puts out

9,8,7,6,9,8,7,6,9,8,7,6,9,8,7,6

So thanks in advance, bye.

Comment: `Zwi` is always _the same list_. You have to create a _new list_ every iteration.

Comment: since list works on references so if you clear the pointed list it will effect the main list that has element  pointing to another list

Comment: Could be that your appending a reference to Zwi. So, it'll be in whatever state Zwi ends at.
A quick way to check is to update the Zwi list after processing, then printing Coords to see if it changes the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: See the linked question for an explanation of what's happening in your code. It's basically the same problem as yours, except you're never even trying to copy your list (or create a new one).

Comment: seems to be working fine here: https://repl.it/OHZy/0

Comment: @AlexEfimov Not sure how you came to that conclusion. If you enter more than 1 list, they'll all be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear your list:

```
Zwi.clear()
```

Make a new one each time:

```
Zwi = []
```

The former uses the same list for each collection of inputs and hence adds the same list four times. The latter creates four new lists. That is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
g = int(input ('How many lists?'))
Coords = []
while g > 0 :
    Zwi = []
    print('')
    print('')
    print('')      
    co = float(input ('object 1'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 2'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 3'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    co = float(input ('object 4'))
    Zwi.append(co)
    Coords.append(Zwi)
    g = g - 1
print(Coords)
```